# Get the element array position matching the query

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm looping through an array of items to check the corresponding element in order to display them in the correct order.

```js
const array1 = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
const array2 = ["two", "three", "one", "four"]
 
      for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        console.log(array1);
         console.log(array1.filter((element) => array2.includes(element)));
       // here I'm trying to iterate through each element of array1 and find the corresponding element in array2.
   
      }
```

The expected output should be something like :

```
the corresponding array of array1[0] is array2[2],
the corresponding array of array1[1] is array2[1],
and so on.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like that:

```js
const array1 = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
const array2 = ["two", "three", "one", "four"]

for (const [a1Idx, a1] of array1.entries()) {
  const a2Idx = array2.indexOf(a1)
  if (a2Idx >= 0) {
    console.log(`The corresponding array of array1[${a1Idx}] is array2[${a2Idx}]`)
  }
}
```

The [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method returns the index of the searched value, but -1 if the value was not found.

Comment: You're right @pilchard, I updated my answer to a similar approach with `array.entries()` to reduce even more boilerplate code

Answer (score 1):

You can check the index of array1 against array2 with nested loop.

```js
const array1 = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
const array2 = ["two", "three", "one", "four"]
 
      for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
       for (var j =0; j<array2.length; j++){
                if (array1[i] == array2[j]){
                    console.log("the corresponding array of array1["+i+"] is array2["+j+"]")
            }
        }
   
      }
```

Comment: A working solution, but nested loops are kind of inefficient. Using built-in methods to search for a matching value or index may be a better option.

Answer (score 0):

is that what you want?

```js
let array1 = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
let array2 = ["two", "three", "one", "four"]
 
array1.sort((o1,o2) => {
    let p1 = array2.findIndex((o) =>o === o1);
    let p2 = array2.findIndex((o) =>o === o2);
    return p1 < p2 ? -1 : (p1 > p2 ? 1 : 0);
}).forEach(o => console.log(o))
```

Comment: 我更新了下你的答案样式，这样就能直接执行看效果了，不过看起来不像是提问人要求的答案

Comment: no, the OP wants the matching indexes of the original ordering logged.

Comment: @pilchard Nice to see you again,do you have some more elegant solution?

Comment: @lucumt it's always going to be a nested loop unless one wants to make a lookup table.

Comment: Hi, thanks, maybe the lookup table is more elegant, but I don't know how to achieve that

Comment: @Aurore a nested loop, like either of the upvoted answers is a fine solution for smaller arrays. A lookup table would be useful if you were dealing with *very* large arrays, or repeatedly comparing against the same array.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still new to it and I learned how to use it